# Wordpress Network per site Custom URL Slugs

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm attempting to setup a Multisite Wordpress Network, but one of the requirements is that each site needs to have their own custom slug in the URL. For example:

```
http://www.site1.com/blog/
http://www.site2.com/reviews/
http://www.site3.com/commentary/
```

Currently, so far as I can tell, there is no way of tailoring a per site slug. Domain Mapping is simple using the plugin [Wordpress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) (It's compatible with Wordpress 3+ Networks.) But what I really need is the added ability of those custom slugs. Has anyone seen anything of that sort?

I'll revert to a large collection of individual Wordpress Instances if I have to, but this network setup would be the perfect solution if I could get the slugs to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resulting research is that you can't do what I was after with the default build of Wordpress using the Multisite features and the [Wordpress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/).

The arrangement can work sub-directory separation of sites, but the only way to allow the sub-directory to exist for domain mapped addresses is to build an entirely new plugin that does the domain mapping with support for that, or to modify the [Wordpress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) plugin so that it has the support for it, effectively creating a new plugin out of it.

Answer (score 0):

The slugs have nothing to do with your multisite setup. Look into modifying each site's [permalink](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) structure instead.

**UPDATE**

Maybe try to write your own [rewrite rules](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite)?

Comment: Unfortunately unique per site rewrites won't work with Network sites. Subdomain networks are forced to root '/' and even if you make an elaborate rewrite to try and force people to use a '/reviews/', etc, the Wordpress links will try and force you back to the root again. The solution has to be supported internally within Wordpress as well.

Comment: Maybe try to write your own [rewrite rules](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite)?

Comment: Hmm. Hadn't seen that section. Is definitely the best potential yet. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately these don't override the built in references to point the URL to the root. Thus while the initial connection using the rewrite works (ie, connecting to http://www.site2.com/reviews/) clicking onto any of the links themselves send you back to the root for the URL.